# C++ printf: newline (\n) from commandline argument

Tags: c++, string, formatting, newline, printf

How print format string passed as argument ?

example.cpp:

```
#include <iostream> 
int main(int ac, char* av[]) 
{
     printf(av[1],"anything");
     return 0;
}
```

try:

```
example.exe "print this\non newline"
```

output is:

```
print this\non newline
```

instead I want:

```
print this
on newline
```

Comment: The fact that this question needs asking at all shows a weakness in the Windows command shell. In the Unix shell, you can send argument strings that contain newline characters.

Comment: Check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack
By doing something like printf(argv[1]); you give the user complete freedom to make your program do whatever the user wants to do. The stack can be printed by passing "%08x" and memory can be overwritten using %n.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, do not do that! That is a very severe vulnerability. You should never accept format strings as input. If you would like to print a newline whenever you see a "\n", a better approach would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     if ( argc != 2 ){
         std::cerr << "Exactly one parameter required!" << std::endl;
         return 1;
     }

     int idx = 0;
     const char* str = argv[1];
     while ( str[idx] != '\0' ){
          if ( (str[idx]=='\\') && (str[idx+1]=='n') ){
                 std::cout << std::endl;
                 idx+=2;
          }else{
                 std::cout << str[idx];
                 idx++;
          }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Or, if you are including the Boost C++ Libraries in your project, you can use the `boost::replace_all` function to replace instances of "\\n" with "\n", as suggested by Pukku.

Comment: /me runs the program with a few copies of `%n` in the format string...mmmm.... :-P

Comment: -1 Vulnerability aside, how is your "answer" answering the OP's question?

Comment: Blanket statements are also dangerous. This would be perfectly fine in an environment where you have control over the parameters, via batch file for example.

Comment: @PoweRoy: An untrusted format string can be used to corrupt memory in arbitrary ways. For example, with the `%n` format I mentioned, it writes out the number of currently-written characters into the address pointed to by the next argument. Since the attacker controls the whole format string (in this case), they also have control of what value gets written. Embed a few more `%n` and you get even more scribbling.

Comment: @Mark, you might think you have control... but just wait until it ends up in a huge code base with other code from the organization. Do you have any idea how difficult it would be to track down and prevent it from ending up elsewhere? Better not to let that ever enter your codebase to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

At least if I understand correctly, you question is really about converting the "\n" escape sequence into a new-line character. That happens at compile time, so if (for example) you enter the "\n" on the command line, it gets printed out as "\n" instead of being converted to a new-line character.

I wrote some [code](http://c.snippets.org/snip_lister.php?fname=translat.c) *years* ago to convert escape sequences when you want it done. Please don't pass it as the first argument to printf though. If you want to print a string entered by the user, use fputs, or the "%s" conversion format:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    if (argc > 1) 
        printf("%s", translate(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dead link. Archived: https://web.archive.org/web/20080303102232/http://c.snippets.org/snip_lister.php?fname=translat.c

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because `\n` and the like are parsed by the C compiler. In the generated code, the actual numerical value is written.

What this means is that your input string will have to actually contain the character value 13 (or 10 or both) to be considered a new line because the C functions *do not know how to handle these special characters since the C compiler does it for them*.

Alternatively you can just replace every instance of `\\n` with `\n` in your string before sending it to `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

passing user arguments directly to printf causes a exploit called "String format attack"

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack) and [Much more details](http://seclists.org/bugtraq/2000/Sep/214)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to automatically have the string contain a newline.  You'll have to do some kind of string replace on your own before you use the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It is only the compiler that converts \n etc to the actual ASCII character when it finds that sequence in a string.

If you want to do it for a string that you get from somewhere, you need to manipulate the string directly and replace the string "\n" with a CR/LF etc. etc.

If you do that, don't forget that "\\" becomes '\' too.

Please never ever use char* buffers in C++, there is a nice std::string class that's safer and more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer but is this thread is active ?
btw

you can try
example.exe "print this$(echo -e "\n ")on newline".

I tried and executed
Regards,
Shahid nx