# How to get console window input to make newlines act like newlines?

Tags: c++

How can I make std::getline treat newlines like newline characters in a hard-coded string would be treated?

I have this code:

```
std::string sServerRequest;
std::getline(std::cin, sServerRequest);
std::cout << sServerRequest;
```

If I type this input in the console:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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\ncfN3bGu1AsZGtey3CBY=\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n
```

This is the output in the console window (not desirable for my application):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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\ncfN3bGu1AsZGtey3CBY=\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n
```

This code:

```
std::string sServerRequest= "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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\ncfN3bGu1AsZGtey3CBY=\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n";
std::cout << "Specify Server Request" << std::endl;
std::cout << sServerRequest;
```

Produces this result in the console window (desirable):

```
Specify Server Request
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

^How can I change my logic to treat newlines like the hard-coded string did? Is there some escaping going on that I need to remove?

The logic that handles the contents of sServerRequest expects the format of the string to be in the format of the second example (marked as desirable in this question). The printing of the characters isn't all that important. What's important is what is in sServerRequest. My logic that processes it can handle the second case but not the first.

Comment: Related (maybe dupe): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782682/will-cin-recognize-n-typed-in-from-keyboard-as-a-newline-character) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508796/c-printf-newline-n-from-commandline-argument/2508814#2508814)

Comment: @hnefatl Windows shell

Comment: Fair enough, but the process is probably very similar (EDIT: looking again, that first link is OS agnostic). Regardless, would it be that difficult to have a find/replace function that swaps the sequence `\n` for an actual newline?

Comment: ReadConsole includes new line into read buffer

Comment: Why the down votes? Not like everyone born with the knowledge that newlines have to be escaped with newlines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had the desired result:

```
std::string sServerRequest;
std::cout << "Specify Server Request" << std::endl;
std::getline(std::cin, sServerRequest);

size_t f;

do
{
    f = sServerRequest.find(
        "\\n"
    );

    if (f != std::string::npos)
    {

        sServerRequest.replace(
            f,
            std::string("\\n").length(),
            "\n"
        );
    }
} while (f != std::string::npos);

std::cout << sServerRequest;
```

Thanks.