# newline from user input without pressing enter

Tags: c++, user-input, cin

First of all, I should mention that I found several closely related questions. Eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782682/will-cin-recognize-n-typed-in-from-keyboard-as-a-newline-character) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508796/c-printf-newline-n-from-commandline-argument/2508814#2508814). However, neither do I want to use `printf` nor do I want to use `\n` (because I know already that it does not work).

**Is it possible for the user to enter a newline, probably an escape sequence, without hitting enter?**

As an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () {
    std::string a,b;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << a << "\n" << b;
}
```

Is it possible for a user to provide a single line of input

```
hello ??? world
```

such that the above prints

```
hello
world
```

?

Comment: @L.F. I do press enter but only once, so the first `cin` should read until `???` and the second the rest because its still in the stream

Comment: When you enter `Hello World` with a space in between, `a` will be set to `"Hello"` and `b` will be set to `"World"`. Is that what you want? https://ideone.com/bVxZdt

Comment: I'm obligated to ask: but why?

Comment: @mch thats the obvious answer to the question, but unfortunately not what I actually wanted. The example is actually completely besides the point of what I actually wanted. I dont want to fix the question as there are already answers...

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

> std::string a, b;
>   std::cin >> a>>b;
>   std::cout << a << "\n" << b;

User can give input with space.

Comment: `std::cin >> a>>b;` does exactly the same as `std::cin >> a; std::cin >> b;`.

Comment: hum thats a bit embarrsing... my example was not really what i actually wanted. Of course simply entering "hello world" will already generate the correct input. I actually wanted to read two lines with a single get line, but now I realize that this is non sense. Apologize for the confusion...thanbks for the answer anyhow

Comment: What if the user wants to include space in their strings?

Answer (score 1):

(I assume that you do not want spaces to delimit strings. For example,

```
Foo bar ??? baz qux
```

should be two lines.)

It is not possible that you configure the streams so that `???` is automatically converted to a newline character. For the user to input a newline character, they have to input a newline character, not anything else.

You have to parse it yourself.
Here's an example parser that treats `???` as delimiter:

```
void read_string(std::istream& is, std::string& dest)
{
  std::string str = "";
  for (char c; is.get(c);) {
    switch (c) {
    case '?':
      if (is.get(c) && c == '?') {
        if (is.get(c) && c == '?') {
          dest = str;
          return;
        } else {
          str += "??";
        }
      } else {
        str += "?";
      }
    default:
      str += c;
    }
  }
}
```

For example, the input

```
? is still one question mark????? is still two question marks???
```

is parsed as two lines:

```
? is still one question mark
?? is still two question marks
```

[<kbd>live demo</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/adNnuLvlXuzVztZK)

Comment: hum thats a bit embarrsing... my example was not really what i actually wanted. Of course simply entering "hello world" will already generate the correct input. I actually wanted to read two lines with a single get line, but now I realize that this is non sense. Apologize for the confusion... thanks for the answer anyhow

Comment: what I really wanted was two consecutive calls to `getline` reading user input and the user has to press enter only once. As thats something completely different, I'll just leave this question as is and maybe open a new one.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 The streams don't do this kind of conversion for you ;-)

Comment: I guess if it is possible somehow then only via some feature provided by the terminal I am using, something that would interpret some escape sequence as new line. And I guess I should have my first coffee before asking the first question next time ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 That's outside the scope of C++ I/O streams. ;-)